# Detect null column value in PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php project that uses mysqli to query a database. Some of the columns in this database can be null. I have code that looks something like this:

```
$query = "...";
$result = $DB->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$column = $row['mycolumn'];
```

If `mycolumn` is null, the value of `$column` appears to be the string, `"NULL"` (NOT the null value, but actually the string containing the word "NULL"). So what happens if I have columns which actually have the string `"NULL"` in them? How can I differentiate?

Thanks!
Josh

EDIT:
Upon closer inspection, it appears that the string is actually a 5-characters string. The first 4 characters are `"NULL"`, but the last character is 0x0d, the carriage return. This makes it a lot easier to detect, although I'm still curious if there's a less hack-y way than just doing string comparison.

Comment: You should try [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) in your query

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
"Note: This function sets NULL fields to the PHP NULL value."
So the problem is a bug in PHP or an issue somewhere else.  Or maybe it was in 2013 but is fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

Use an `if` condition to check with `===`

```
if($row['mycolumn'] === null) {
   echo 'Real Null';
} elseif($row['mycolumn'] == '') {
   echo 'Blank';
}
```

Comment: `$row['mycolumn']` is actually the string, "NULL", not the null value.

Comment: So use this `if($row['mycolumn'] == "NULL") {echo 'String Null';}`

Comment: @mr-alien, I get that. My problem is that the mysql database is returning "NULL" for null values. This causes problems if I want to have a string entry whose value is "NULL," because I won't be able to tell the difference between the two from PHP. It's actually not QUITE as big of an issue as it could be (see the last edit to the post that I made), but it would still be nice to not have to do string comparison on the off chance that I want to store the actual word "NULL" in my database.

Comment: @joshlf13 You are not getting our conditions right, and any explanation for -1 whoever has voted?

Comment: @Mr.Alien It is community who is downvoting for wrong answers. Yesterday I also get -1.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking wrong way. Instead of trying to detect **wrong** NULL value you have to find out **why** it is wrong and correct it.

#### Neither Mysql nor mysqli would return a literal string 'NULL' for a null value.

So, you need to find your own code which converts NULL value to "NULL\n" string either at writing or reading. Are you using raw mysqli as $DB or it's a sort of abstraction class? If so - I'd say problem is there.

After that you can easily read NULL value with strict comparison `===` as suggested in other answers (though I am not sure about libmysql installations).

Answer (score 0):

seems the column have the data type as string.

If it is string,

we can check by following

```
if($row['mycolumn'] == '' || is_null($row['mycolumn']))
{
    echo "Coulmn is NULL value";
}
else if($row['mycolumn'] == "NULL")
{
    echo "Coulmn is NULL value as string";
}
```

Comment: `$row['mycolumn']` is actually the string, "NULL", not the null value.

Comment: do you want to get the query to fetch the rows that the column have the value NULL?

Comment: close. I want to be able to tell the difference, in my result set, between fields which are null in the MySQL sense and which simply have the string "NULL" as their contents.